# DataTables 1.10+ - How do I access pageLength/number of rows per page/page.info().length in a Pagination Plug-in function

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination, datatables-1.10

I need a custom DataTables Pagination Plug-in for my server side page to show a max of `skip + take = 10000` records, so I am writing one taking a cue from the [Simple Numbers - No Ellipses](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses) plugin.
The maximum of 10000 records is because the data comes from ElasticSearch which has [this limitation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20you%20cannot%20use%20from%20and%20size%20to%20page%20through%20more%20than%2010%2C000%20hits.%20This%20limit%20is%20a%20safeguard%20set%20by%20the%20index.max_result_window%20index%20setting.%20If%20you%20need%20to%20page%20through%20more%20than%2010%2C000%20hits%2C%20use%20the%20search_after%20parameter%20instead.) when using simple offset-based pagination.
Anyway, to return to the question, how do I access the number of rows per page inside the custom pagination plugin function?
This value can be set at [initialization time](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) as an option or can be queried ([page.info().length](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()) or directly [page.len()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len())) provided one have a DataTable API instance, which I don't think I can access since that plugin is generic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dataTableExt`

https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/features

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.myplugin = {
  'fnInit': function(oSettings, nPaging, fnCallbackDraw) {
    let api = oSettings.oInstance.api();
    console.log(api.page.info())
  },
  'fnUpdate': function(oSettings, fnCallbackDraw) {

  }
};

$('#example').DataTable({
  'sPaginationType': 'myplugin'
});
```

**Note:** Refer other [pagination  plug-ins](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/#Plug-ins)

Comment: This is the correct way to do pagination with DataTables up to version 1.9 (ref: https://legacy.datatables.net/development/pagination). But, as the title and tags say, I am on version 1.10 which doesn't yet have documentation (ref: https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/#:~:text=not.%20Read%20more%20%C2%BB-,Paging%20plug%2Din%20development,-Update%20for%201.10)

Comment: @Oliver `settings` is not exposed in modern API. But I found the [source code](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/b1df9fd6bc5183db2f1aa9c5ac45197add6a442e/js/core/core.page.js#L19) where the legacy version is also supported.

Comment: Good find, how would I use that in my situation?

Comment: Probably you have to use the legacy approach. I don't find any solution.